# WinDivert: What is the reason behind the error: "failed to open WinDivert handle (err = 3)

Tags: dll, driver

My code was working fine yesterday, but I moved some files around to a different repository and then restarted my computer overnight and now my code won't compile.

I tried running the test.exe that comes with the pre-compiled binaries on the WinDivert website (https://reqrypt.org/windivert.html) , but they keep giving me an error (3). Not sure what the error means.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.